# XML verification with XSD: attribute is not declared. But it is - see example

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm having a problem validating XML against schema. Simplified code and examples:

Verification code:

```
    public static void ValidateXmlAgainstSchema(StreamReader xml, XmlSchema xmlSchema)
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true, IgnoreComments = true };
        settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);

        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (obj, args) => { if (args.Exception != null) throw args.Exception; };

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings))
        using (XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
        {
            while (validatingReader.Read()){}
        }
    }
```

Schema:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://foo.com/"
           xmlns="http://foo.com/">

  <xs:simpleType name="myBool">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="true"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="false"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="file_not_found"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="dataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="data" type="dataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="myBool" type="myBool" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML:

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo xmlns="http://foo.com/" myBool="true">
  <data>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>abc</name>
  </data>
</foo>
```

This example throws an exception:

System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element 'foo' in namespace 'http://foo.com/' has invalid child element 'data'
in namespace 'http://foo.com/'. List of possible elements expected: 'data'.

My understanding is that if the namespace is defined for an element, all child elements will have the same namespace, unless defined otherwise. It doesn't work though. I can make it validate by adding elementFormDefault="qualified" to the schema, which makes all elements default to targetNamespace. Is that a good way of doing it?

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:foo xmlns:a="http://foo.com/" a:myBool="true">
  <a:data>
    <a:id>1</a:id>
    <a:name>abc</a:name>
  </a:data>
</a:foo>
```

This example fails with the message:

The 'http://foo.com/:myBool' attribute is not declared.

Every element and attribute has an explicit namespace, so the xml should be valid. Even the error message suggest parser is looking for the attribute I expect it to, but fails to find it. I can make it validate by changing a:myBool to myBool. Why doesn't it work in the first form and works in the other?

Answer (score 2):

`elementFormDefault` won't do anything to attributes, to set the equivilent for those you need `attributeFormDefault`. However, by default both of these are set to "unqualified".

The reason approach 2 - `a:myBool="true"` - failed is becuase the `attributeFormDefault` value wasn't overridden. If you want to namespace attributes, you can either set this to "qualified" **or** set the `form` attribute on the attribute declaration itself to "qualified", like so:

```
<xs:attribute name="myBool" type="myBool" use="optional" form="qualfied"/>
```

This should make this a valid element start for approach 2:

```
<a:foo xmlns:a="http://foo.com/" a:myBool="true">
```

As for why approach 1 failed, I'm not sure, your XSD and XML match. It might be worth adding setting the `attributeFormDefault` attribute on the root XSD element to "unqualified", just in case the XSLT engine doesn't recognise their default settings when they aren't declared. Like so:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://foo.com/"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
       xmlns="http://foo.com/">
```

Comment: I thought that if element is in certain namespace (either explicitly or using elementFormDefault), all attributes within in would default to the same namespace...

I've added the `form="qualified"`, which indeed made the 2nd form valid. But now the 1st is invalid. Is there a schema which validates both? They seem equivalent to me, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there's a schema that would allow both. At least, the two are NOT equivalent - because default namespaces ONLY apply to elements, not to attributes. Presumably this is because it is assumed that ONE author has control over the format of one element, so that name-clashing in attribute names is not an issue.